# Preventing Truncation of First Post

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm looking for a way to prevent only the first post on the blog index from being truncated (showing the post snippet and featured image).

So the full contents of the most recent post would be output, then all other after that would be displayed as normal.

Is there any way to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

By truncating, do you mean using [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) rather than `the_content()`? Or do you mean using `the_content()` with [`<!--more-->` tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) ?.

In either case, you can alter how a post behaves by using the following:

```
<?php 
 if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        //We check that we are this is the first post in the loop AND
        //that we are on page one.
        //(Probably unnecessary) but to be safe you can uncomment the next line
        //global $wp_query;
        if(!is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post==0){
             //First post of first page, show full content using the_content();
             //This will display up to the first <!--more--> tag - not clear if you are using this.

        }else{
             //Otherwise display the post as normal / using the_excerpt();
        }

    endwhile; 
  endif; 
 ?>
```